# xamarin grid always wrong size

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried explicitly setting heights, column definitions, but I cannot get the sizing here to be correct.
I tried setting two columns with one row, with and without explicit heights and sizes.

What do I have to do?

[image: am]

Comment: Where are your ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions?

Comment: Nothing in this screemshot. I originally tried what you'd do in wpf world with 2 columns and rows. Columns widths set to 8* and 2*. Second row text box with a span of 2. Tried with and without explicit heights. From what I've read, if you don't provide any, they'll be implicit in the xamarin grid. I tried adding an explicit one row one column definition but didn't get it to properly determine it's height. As I was editing, I saw the designer position two text boxes on the left and right. That's about where I was when I took the screenshot

Comment: please do not post code as images.  I can't copy your XAML which makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score -1):

something like this should work

```
<ViewCell>
  <!-- need to specify an overall height -->
  <Grid HeightRequest="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- two rows equal height -->
      <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="50*" />      
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefintions>
      <!-- two cols equal width -->
      <ColumnDefintions Width="50*" />
      <ColumnDefintions Width="50*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Location" />
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Amount" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Created" />
  </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```